# Add, to bibliographic entries, cross-references or back-references to the pages in the document where citation call-outs occur

Tags: hyperref, citing

In the bibliography, is it possible to add (possibly hyperlinked) cross-references to the page(s) where a given entry is cited?
I use natbib.

Example:

```
[1] Donald Knuth, Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,    p 22, 33
```

where `p 22, 33` are hyperlinks to the pages in document where I `\cite{}` this bibliographic entry.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to bring out the intended purpose more directly. Are you familiar with the `backref` package, which is loaded automatically if the `hyperref` package is loaded with the option `backref` or `backref=page`?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this package option `backref=page` :)
When I tried to use it, some error has occured: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref`... but I manged to handle it by moving this option `backref=page` to `\documentclass` declaration.

Comment: @andywiecko - Which document class do you use?

Comment: `report` class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the `hyperref` package with the (additional) option `backref=page`.

A full MWE (compile it by running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more), showing just the third and final page of output:

[image]

The blue numbers "1" and "2" are the page numbers on which the entry was cited. Clicking on either number (in the pdf file) will make the file browswer jump to the associated page.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa, author = "Annie Author", title = "Thoughts", year = 3001,}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue,
            backref=page]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citet{aa} \clearpage
\citep{aa} \clearpage
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```